# The system field 'weight' is disappeared from backoffice

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute

When I try to insert a new product I don't find the system field `weight` in the `General` attribute group.
It is present in the `Manage Attribute Sets` but not in the `Manage Products`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Means you missed "weight" attribute from "General" attribute group, but it is listed in "Manage Attribute Sets", Do you not find weight attribute in the right section panel from where you can assign attributes to the group in Attribute sets?

Comment: No, I don't find 'weight attribute' in the 'General' section of the interface used to insert a new product.